# Is composition of isomorphism and complementation of a graph commutative?

Tags: functions, commutative-algebra, function-and-relation-composition, graph-isomorphism

Composition of two functions, ${f_1}$ and ${f_2}$, is commutative if ${f_1} \circ {f_2} = {f_2} \circ {f_1}$.
Even when the functions are **bijective**, **it is not necessary** that their composition is **commutative**.
My question is, given two specific bijective functions, **isomorphism** and **complementation** on a graph $G$, is their composition commutative?

I realized that if two graphs $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic, then their complements are also isomorphic. This led me to see (ref below proof by contradiction) that the above composition is commutative. Can anyone pls tell me if this is correct! It would be great if you could point out any other theory that has led to similar conclusion.

My reasoning:
By contradiction, ${f_1} \circ {f_2} (G) \not= {f_2} \circ {f_1} (G)$.

$=>   {f_1} ({f_2}(G))={f_1} (G^{c}) \not= {f_2} ({f_1} (G))= {f_2} (H) = H^{c}$
However, $H^{c}$ and $G^{c}$ are isomorphic.

Comment: I think not, take for example a graph G and a graph H, which is equal to G with one more distinct vertex w (no edges between w to the other vertices).

Comment: @friedvir  - In that case, are G and H isomorphic!

Comment: Sorry didn't notice, then i guess you are right, just need the explanation for why the complement graphs are isomorphic, won't be hard to prove

Comment: @friedvir can you edit the question to make it clear. I have no idea what it's asking

Comment: @mathworker21 its asking if you can switch the order of operation on a graph and still get the same product, if you first map the graph $G$ to $H$ with isomorphism $f$, and then make it the complementary graph of $H$,($H^c$) , or you first make it complementary of $G$, ($G^c$), and then map it to $H^c$, with same isomorphism  $f$.

Comment: @mathworker21 - Composition of two bijective functions (say f1, f2) are not necessarily commutative (i.e. f1 (f2) = f2(f1) ). The question is when the functions represent isomorphism and complementation of a Graph, is the composition commutative?

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by "the function represents complementation". What are the domain and range of the function $f_2$ (vertex sets? edge sets?) and how does it act?

Comment: @bof - Does this http://mathonline.wikidot.com/complement-graphs or this  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphComplement.html help!  $f_{2}(G) = G^{c}$

Comment: I understand perfectly well what the complement of a graph is, but I don't know what **function** you are talking about. For instance, if $G$ has vertex set $V=\{w,x,y,z\}$ and edge set $E=\{wx,xy,yz,wz\}$, then $G^c$ has vertex set $\{w,x,y,z\}$ and edge set $\{wy,xz\}$. But what is the function $f_2:G\to G^c$ that you are talking about? What is $f_2(w)$? Is $f_2$ just the identity map on $V$?

Comment: I always thought 'mapping' and 'function' are interchangeable. If they bring about subtle difference here, I'm afraid I'm not able to figure it out. In terms of function, my understanding is $f_{2}$ has any graph $G$ as its domain and co-domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to think of the operation of complementation as a function you are making things harder to understand than they need to be. You would have to carefully define a class of 'all' graphs. Whether it is an isomorphism on such a class is not relevant to your actual question as I understand it.

If $G$ and $H$ are finite simple graphs and $\varphi: G \rightarrow H$ is a graph isomorphism then $\varphi(G)^C = \varphi(G^C)$ because these two graphs have the vertices and the same edges. So you could say that complementation and applying the isomorphism commute.